# XBee communication in API mode using X-CTU

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I am trying to communicate between two XBee S2 modules both in API mode using the XCTU tool.
One device as router and another device as coordinator.  I got successful communication of two XBee modules in AT mode and either of them as API or AT mode. But when I configure both of them in API mode they are not communicating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving a lot of try i found two tricks in configuring X Bee modules

1. If your X Bee module is not getting read, just write with the suitable firmware
   choosing manually
2. If it is not responding to read or even write also, connect reset pin to 
   ground using single wire for few second.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know they're not communicating?  How are you forming your API frames to send into the device?

In API mode, the XBee module requires a checksummed series of bytes in a specific format to send data to another device.  During your tests between the module in AT mode and the one in API mode, you were probably able to see a received frame on the API module when typing data into X-CTU on the AT module.

What language are you going to write your program in?  I would recommend using a code library to manage encoding and decoding the API frames.

Digi has a webpage listing [XBee host libraries](http://examples.digi.com/quick-reference/) in various languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am sending the in frames only but still i am not getting any response. I am new to this XBee so initially i want to configure two modules to communicate on PC then i code using C language for ARM controller.

Comment: I have an [ANSI C host library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) you could try using.  You can prototype on the PC, and then port to ARM.  I'd recommend working through some of the samples on [Digi's XBee Examples website](http://examples.digi.com/) to better understand how things work, and learn the troubleshooting skills you'll need to build an application with the XBee.